# Force desktop browser to open mobile site

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

I created a web site for my school in 2 versions, one for pc and one for mobile.
I use the following code to check if the device is mobile:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // mobile...
}
```

I want to force some users to direct the mobile site, without changing the code above... can i give to the browser document some property and then the browser will think its mobile?

Comment: Which specific users? How do you determine it?

Comment: You could set the navigator.userAgent property to be one of the strings in your list, and make sure you do that before you run the if statement. But as A. Wolff says, how are you determining who to redirect? You might be better changing your if statement

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the 'Browser Agent' detects screen size, redirecting to the 'correct' version of a site. You could use a Browser Agent Switcher plugin, but that depends on the user having this plugin. If that's what you're after, you can use [this.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/)

On what occasion, or which group of users do you need to see the mobile version. What's the reason? You don't have to give away too many details, but a 'why' may assist in getting what you want.

Kind regards.

ARc

Comment: I should have also mentioned, that if you're after more flexibility to your page... try WhichBrowser.net. I know you said you didn't want to edit your code, but it may be of more use to you and isn't hard to implement. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you mean User Agent, rather than Browser Agent. User agent is a string sent with every webpage request a users browser makes, and contains information about your browser. It is famously unreliable and shouldn't really be relied on. It doesn't contain information on screen size.